# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djfilter.wsgi.application'; 'djfilter.wsgi' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy Django app on Heroku.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djfilter.wsgi.application'; 'djfilter.wsgi' is not a package
```

Comment: djfilter is name of project and not a package. Have you changed the name of project from djfilter to something else.

Comment: Not I downloaded a boilerplate project on github named liked that

Comment: Yeah I know, have you followed the tutorial properly. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-X1KMCM_uts&ab_channel=JustDjango)

Comment: Yes I did follow the tutorial you mention, I have no problem running the application locally the problem occurred while trying to deploy it on Heroku.